# Pandas Dataframes append

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, concatenation

I need to append a DataFrame (50 rows) to another (same structure) every iteration, i have a loop with 10000 iteration, it takes about 10 minutes to generate the final DataFrame.

```
out = pd.DataFrame()
tmp = res.copy()  #my initial DataFrame with 50 rows 

for nb in range(1,10001) :
    ...
    ...
    #some code here to
    match = (res.COL06 == 'PCE')
    tmp['COL06'] = np.where(match,res["CLE"].map(lambda x : x.ljust(12-len(str(nb)),'0')) + str(nb),res["COL06"]) 
    ...

    out = pd.concat([out,tmp],ignore_index='True',axis=0)
```

Is there any other way to do this ?

Comment: I don't know whether you spend most of your time in the `concat` function, but you can try `out = out.append(tmp, ignore_index=True)`

Comment: i got a same result with append :(

Answer (score 0):

It seems a lot like the concatenation operation is not your real bottleneck. I concatenated 10,000 DataFrames with 50 rows each in about 22 seconds using your method. So unless there is some funny stuff happening, or your DataFrames are very wide (I just used 1 column), your best shot might be to profile your code (using e.g. `pdb`) and look for the part that really consumes the most resources (which should always be your first step when running into performance issues).

However, if you are positive that your concatenations are slowing you down significantly, you can first write all of the `tmp` DataFrames into a Python list, and concatenate all of them at once after the loop:

```
import pandas as pd

def append1(n): # your method
    out = pd.DataFrame()
    for nb in range(n):
        tmp = pd.DataFrame({"val": range(nb,50+nb)})
        out = pd.concat([out,tmp],ignore_index='True',axis=0)
    return out

def append2(n): # concatenate after loop
    out = pd.DataFrame()
    tmp_list = []
    for nb in range(n):
        tmp = pd.DataFrame({"val": range(nb,50+nb)})
        tmp_list.append(tmp)
    out = pd.concat(tmp_list,ignore_index='True',axis=0)
    return out
```

Performance impact:

```
%timeit append1(10000)
```

1 loop, best of 3: 22.4 s per loop

```
%timeit append2(10000)
```

1 loop, best of 3: 4.15 s per loop

Comment: i have dataframes with 55 columns !!

Comment: Alright, in this case 10 minutes might be realistic. Did you try my proposed change? Should at least let your code run five times faster.